# Postgres как узнать имя sequence

Tags: sql, postgresql

можно ли у таблицы узнать имя зависимости (первичный ключ). имя не первичного ключа, а имя зависимости. нужно для

> currval('seq_name')

Comment: Заголовок не отображает суть вопроса

Answer (score 2, accepted):

так можно получить через представления с каким SEQUENCE установлена связь
(имя таблицы 'table1' поменяйте на своё):

```
SELECT  t.column_name, t.column_default
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS t
WHERE t.table_schema = 'public'
AND t.table_name = 'table1' 
AND t.column_default is not null
```

связь между полем таблицы и последовательностью (OWNED BY)
прописана в таблице pg_depend, где refobjid = pg_attribute.attrelid (колонка), а поле objid = pg_class.oid для объекта SEQUENCE :

```
select a.attname, c.relname
FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
inner join pg_depend as d on d.refobjid = a.attrelid 
inner join pg_class c on c.oid = d.objid
WHERE a.attrelid = 'table1'::regclass AND a.attnum > 0 AND d.deptype = 'a' and a.atthasdef = true
```

Answer (score 0):

можно.

запрос ниже покажет все ключи таблицы, их имена и типы. вместо schema и table нужно подставить свои значения.

```
SELECT  kcu.column_name, kcu.constraint_name, tc.constraint_type  
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t 
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc  ON tc.table_catalog = t.table_catalog AND tc.table_schema = t.table_schema  AND tc.table_name = t.table_name 
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE kcu ON kcu.table_catalog = tc.table_catalog  AND kcu.table_schema = tc.table_schema AND kcu.table_name = tc.table_name AND kcu.constraint_name = tc.constraint_name
WHERE  t.table_schema NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') 
AND t.table_schema like %schema% 
AND t.table_name like %table%
```

Comment: отдает column_name, constraint_name, constraint_type, а мне нужен SEQUENCE